# Adding directory to the path in .zshrc

Tags: osx-lion, zsh, zshrc

I have been on this issue for a couple days now. I use `zsh` and need to set a directory path so that the command i use will be recognized. Following these steps so far:

```
cd ~

ls -al
```

`ls -al` shows me these files:

```
.oh-my-zsh
.profile
.putty
.rediscli_history
.ringo-history
.ssh
.subversion
.viminfo
.zcompdump
.zsh-update
.zsh_history
.zshrc
```

I assume i need to add the path to `.zshrc`, so:

```
open -e .zshrc
```

At the end of the file, i added the path of the command i will be using to set my project (with ringojs):

```
export PATH=Users/repos/ringojs/bin/:$PATH
```

Close the file, restart the terminal application, restart the computer, however the command (`ringo-admin`) located under the path above (`/Users/repos/ringojs/bin`) is not found:

```
ringo-admin create --google-appengine MyAppName
zsh: command not found: ringo-admin
```

Please help me with that, if it will of some help, here is my `.zshrc` file content:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Comment this out to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment to change how many often would you like to wait before auto-updates occur? (in days)
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# Customize to your needs...
export PATH=Users/repos/ringojs/bin/ringo-admin:$PATH
```

Please guide me step by step, as i am new to `zsh`. Thanx.

**UPDATE:**

echo $PATH display me the recently added directory:

```
/Users/repos/ringojs/bin/ringo-admin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

I don't understand why the command is always not found.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are missing a leading slash.  Try:

```
export PATH=/Users/repos/ringojs/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. However, i already try it. Always the same issue.

Comment: In your example, you have `export PATH=Users/repos/ringojs/bin/ringo-admin:$PATH`.  Are you removing the trailing `ringo-admin` as you ought?

Comment: here is the `echo $PATH` result: `/Users/repos/ringojs/bin/ringo-admin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`So the added directory path is added to the `.zshrc` config file. But why the command is still not found?

Comment: I solved the problem, all i need is that path: `export PATH=/Users/repos/ringojs/bin:$PATH` So without the final slash and command name, only the directory name `bin`. Yes i should remove the `ringo-admin` from the path, only specify the directory where the command reside. Now that works fine. Thanx :)

Comment: Don't forget to restart zsh `source ~/.zshrc`